# How to create jlist from left corner to right corner?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jlist

i am creating a jlist  using swing and i want to create that list from top most right corner to top most left corner how can i do that

i did following code

```
package demoipis;


import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CreateList{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  String subject[] = {"Math   English"};
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Creating a JList Component");
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); 
  int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());  
int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight()); 
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  JList list = new JList(subject);
  frame.setUndecorated(true);
  frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG);
  panel.add(list);
  frame.add(panel);
  frame.setSize(xSize,ySize);  
//frame.show();  

  frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

how can i achieve desired output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the list directly to JFrame and get rif of the *panel*.

Comment: can you pay for the code?

Comment: Instead of paying why don't you just follow the advice given? Get rid of the panel (is it not needed) and add the scrollpane to the frame as I demonstrated. If it doesn't work then post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i made this change but not working         JList list = new JList(subject);
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
  frame.add(scrollPane, BorederLayout.NORTH);
  frame.setUndecorated(true);
  frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG);
  frame.add(list);
  //frame.add(panel);
  frame.setSize(xSize,ySize);  
//frame.show();  

  frame.setVisible(true);

Comment: @user3377703, don't post code in a comment. How do you expect us to read that?

Comment: so i will have to post code again in code section ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default layout of a JFrame is a BorderLayout. So add your JList to a JScrollPane and add the scrollpane to the NORTH of the BorderLayout.

```
JList list = new JLIst(...);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
frame.add(scrollPane, BorederLayout.NORTH);
```

now the list will take all the horizontal space of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Demo example :

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;

    class CreateList{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 String subject[] = {"Math", " English", "  Hindhi", "   java", "  c ", " c++ "," cobol ","          python          ruby and rail                c#            .net         asp.net                           Haskell "};
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Creating a JList Component");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); 
int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());  
int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight()); 
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JList list = new JList(subject);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG);

frame.add(panel);
frame.setSize(xSize,ySize);  
frame.show();  

frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

[image]